# Java Jackson, Marshalling class with Map<String, Object> without access to the class code base

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, marshalling

I'm trying to marshall (serialize) class using Jackson mapper.
Class has Map property. Property has to have some kind of serialization... everything i got was a serialized byte stream or badly serialized map.toString().

I've tried using mixins or setup Jackson mapper... without any help.

com.fasterxml.jackson 2.8.11
com.rabbitmq.client   5.4.3

My Code:

```java
private RawMessage parseMetadata(RawMessage rawMessage, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);


    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();

    JsonNode message = mapper.valueToTree(new String(rawMessage.getPayload()));
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("message", message);

    JsonNode envelopeNode = mapper.valueToTree(envelope);
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("envelope", envelopeNode);

    JsonNode propertiesNode = mapper.valueToTree(properties);
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("properties", propertiesNode);

    return new RawMessage(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsBytes(rootNode));
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "bodySize": 0,
    "headers": {
      "connection_name": {
        "bytes": "MTcyLjE5LjAuMTo0NTgzNiAtPiAxNzIuMTkuMC40OjU2NzI=",
        "stream": {
          "in": { "buf": "MTcyLjE5LjAuMTo0NTgzNiAtPiAxNzIuMTkuMC40OjU2NzI=", "pos": 0, "mark": 0, "count": 35 },
          "bytearr": "A...",
          "chararr": "\u0000...",
          "readBuffer": "AAAAAAAAAAA="
        }
      },
      "timestamp_in_ms": 1565957758662,
      "protocol": {
        "bytes": "ezAsOSwxfQ==",
        "stream": {
          "in": { "buf": "ezAsOSwxfQ==", "pos": 0, "mark": 0, "count": 7 },
          "bytearr": "AAA...",
          "chararr": "\u0000\u0000\...",
          "readBuffer": "AAAAAAAAAAA="
        }
      },...
      },
      "ssl": false
    },
    "deliveryMode": 2,
    "timestamp": 1565957758000,
    "classId": 60,
    "className": "basic"
  }
}
```

```java
class BasicProperties extends com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQBasicProperties {
        private String contentType;
        private String contentEncoding;
        private Map<String,Object> headers; <--- 
        private Integer deliveryMode;
        private Integer priority;
        private String correlationId;
        private String replyTo;
        private String expiration;
        private String messageId;
        private Date timestamp;
        private String type;
        private String userId;
        private String appId;
        private String clusterId;
...}
```

Reproduction:

```java
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
byte[] test =  "test".getBytes();
map.put("test", test);
AMQP.BasicProperties prop = new AMQP.BasicProperties(null, null, map,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

JsonNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();

JsonNode propertiesN = objectMapper.valueToTree(prop);
((ObjectNode) root).set("properties", propertiesN);

LOG.info(root.toString());
```

Result:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "bodySize": 0,
    "headers": { "test": "dGVzdA==" },
    "classId": 60,
    "className": "basic"
  }
}
```

three dots means there's more of it. It's too long. Too many byte streams.

I expect the output of map would be -> key: String

I want to output look like his -> properties.headers.test: "test"

Without any annotation of AMQP.BasicProperties class.

I think that Jacksons Mixins should be the way to do it.

Comment: What is `properties`? And what do you want the `AMQP.BasicProperties` to use for?

Comment: @Lutz Horn   Typo in code... I fixed it. I need to Marshall all of AMQP Properties as json and send it as a RawMessage. RawMessage is just a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question: 
 - make you own Jackson Mixin that annotates your class with custom JsonSerialize Class
 - create you own Serialize class that extends JsonSerializer class
 - register Mixin to mapper with addMixIn(DataClass.class, Mixin.class) method

Example:

Create Mixin

```java
abstract class MixIn {
  @JsonSerialize(using = MyPairSerializer.class)
  abstract Map<String, Object> get_map();
}
```

Create MapSerializer

```java
class MyPairSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> {
  public void serialize(Map<String, Object> map, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      gen.writeStringField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Register Serializer and map object

```java
// API call
Data data = getData();

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = objectMapper.valueToTree(data);
System.out.println("node = " + node);
```

before:
{"data":"test","map":{"test":"dGVzdA=="}}

after:
{"data":"test","map":{"test":"test"}}

TLDR Answer is Mixins with Custom Serializers...